# Stop criterion in foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, parallel-foreach

I need to stop the parallel loop with a condition, e.g., when `res < 1`. A MWE is given by code below

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)    
I <- 1000
L <- 1000
res <- Inf    
cores <- detectCores()
cluster <- makeCluster(cores)
registerDoParallel(cluster)
out <- foreach(l = 1:I,.packages = "cec2013") %dopar% {
    for(i in 1:I){
       res <- 100/i
     }
   out <- res
   out
}
out
```

My tentative to solve is given by

```
out <- foreach(l = 1:I,.packages = "cec2013")%:%when(res < 1)  %dopar% {
    for(i in 1:I){
       res <- 100/i
     }
   out <- res
   out
}
out
```

But `out` return a void list.

Comment: Indeed, it is not very clear why you need the inner for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because `when(res < 1)` looks in the calling environment, not the environment inside the loop.  So you defined `res <- Inf` which is never less than 1.

Also, your foreach loop always returns 0.1, since the inner loop always stops at I=1000, so res will be 0.1.  It's unclear what you're trying to do or when do you expect the loop to stop?

Comment: I need use a criterion inside `foreach` for stop parallel, e.g., `res < 1`. The `res <- Inf` can be removed.

Comment: As I mentioned, your example isn't clear.  All of your iterations go to `res< 1` so nothing will ever finish in your example.

Comment: For example, when `i  = 1`, `res = 100/1`, when `i = 2`, `res = 100/2`, etc. `res < 1` when `i = 101`, in this case I'd like to break.

Comment: Then just use `break` as you're using a normal for loop to iterate over `I`.